# Windows Phone 8 debugging extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-phone-8

Hello fellow programmers,

I have a problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and developing an app for Windows Phone 8.
However it is impossible to use the VS Debugger (both in the emulator and on the device) because it's extremely slow, and I mean really really slow.

I took the following steps to track down the problem:

- Tried different devices (Nokia Lumia 625 & 720) and the emulator, the same problem everywhere
- Tried debugging on different PC - nothing changed
- The app works normally with no debugger attached
- Not definning TRACE or DEBUG doesn't help
- Changing warning levels doesn't help
- I've tracked down the problematic calls:

When in the view there are bindings to specific element in the collection using indexing operator like so:

```
<Button Content="{Binding VisibleAnswers[0].Text}" Tag="{Binding VisibleAnswers[0]}" ...>
```

That goes to the debug output:

> System.Windows.Data Error: Failed to
>   connect to index '0' in object
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Ptaquiz.Mobile.Model.Answer]'
>   (type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Ptaquiz.Mobile.Model.Answer]').
>   BindingExpression: Path='VisibleAnswers[0]'
>   DataItem='Ptaquiz.Mobile.ViewModel.GameViewModel' (HashCode=32789387);
>   target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'
>   (Name='answerButton1'); target property is 'Tag' (type
>   'System.Object').

Failed binding is expected at the beginning, because items are added to the collection later.
Printing each message takes more than a second. What's more, when I've been stepping over my code, I've find out that maniupulating this bound collection (adding, clearing) [only when it's bound to something using the indexing operator] takes more than a second for each operation.

The app works fine without the debugger. With debugger attached it's almost impossible to test it.

I've read that the indexing operator is not supported in Silverlight on which the WP API is based on (?). Is that true? What should I do?

Sorry for bad English.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The VS2013 debugger is excessively slow dealing with exceptions.  No idea what it is doing, hopefully the future Update 1 brings some relief.